# Calling C function from assembly, segfault

Tags: c, function, pointers, assembly, nasm

I'm writing an assembly function to replace letters in a string, char by char, if that char, passed to a function (given by a function pointer param), returns 1.  For instance, if isVowel(c) returns true for the character.  I'm getting a segfault error when I call the function pointer.  I'm using ebx as the number of chars in the string to count back from.

using Linux, Nasm, x86

Here's the assembly function signature in c:

```
int strrepl(char *str, int c, int (* isinsubset) (int c) ) ;
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but:

> -The string pointer is at ebp+8.
>   -The character to replace with is in ebp+12 and takes up 4 bytes (16 bits).
>   -The function pointer is ebp + 28;

Function to call form assembly:

```
int isvowel (int c) {

   if (c == 'a' || c == 'e' || c == 'i' || c == 'o' || c == 'u') 
      return 1 ;

   if (c == 'A' || c == 'E' || c == 'I' || c == 'O' || c == 'U') 
      return 1 ;

   return 0 ;
}
```

Here is my implementation

```
mov     edx, [ebp + 28]
mov     esi, [ebp + 8]
mov     eax, [esi + 4*ebx - 4]
```

gdb is showing eax = 0 after that.  Then,

```
push    eax
call    edx
```

Above produces SEGFAULT

```
add     esp, 4
```

Comment: Calling convention? Which register is used for returns, ecx? Who has to perserve stack, callee or caller? Are you sure it's not the null-terminator screwing with you? :)

Comment: eax is used for returns,  I'll add specs to my post

Comment: Also, eax is where I'm putting that first parameter for the function (the char to check)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - The string pointer is at ebp+8.
> - The character to replace with is in ebp+12 and takes up 4 bytes (16 bits).
> - The function pointer is ebp + 28;

Following your convention, since the function pointer is stored right after the character, its address is `ebp + 16` and not 28. The addresses are byte-oriented not bit-oriented.

Comment: I was about to ask how he came to these conclusions as well.

Comment: That did it.  Yea it was just misunderstanding of the basics.  I thought it might be so I included that bit :P

Comment: @user1736218, it's funny you had got the second argument correctly by adding 4 bytes, but suddenly switched to bits for the third. Anyway, feel free to accept the answer.